# Embedded Gridview Postback into EditMode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, postback

I have a page I'm working on with a Gridview embedded into a Gridview. The page uses templates to fill itself out, including the edittemplate for rows. When the row is in edit mode, 3 of the cells contain dropdownlists.

I'm trying to filter these dropdownlists to prevent conflicts. The problem is that when the page autoposts back, the row is no longer in edit mode. Is it possible to persist edit mode on that row through a postback and apply the filter I need to?

Answer (score 0):

The GridView should be in edit mode, even after the postback. Maybe you are forcing a DataBind in Page_Load or some other event.

Comment: I think the issue with it is because its a GridView within a Gridview. The inner grid does it bound in the outer grids RowBound event, but if I don't bind the data in the inner grid, it doesn't show up at all, at least the way this is designed. I was put onto this project after it was already in development so I'm just picking up where it was left off.